# Download List of Files Simultaneously in PHP

Tags: php

With PHP I create an array of a CSV file containing URLs to files I want to download with this line:

```
$urls = explode(',',file_get_contents('urls.csv'));
```

After this is done, I use the following block of code.

```
foreach($urls as $url){
    $fname = 'not important right now ;)'
    $fcon = fopen($fname,'w');
    fwrite($fcon,file_get_contents($url));
    fclose($fcon);
}
```

**This works great, it downloads all the files in the file!**

But unfortunately, it is not as efficient as I would want it. I want 2,3 or maybe 4 simultaneous downloads to save myself some time. How can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to `curl` you can use [curl_multi_exec](https://www.php.net/curl_multi_exec). First chunk your `$urls` array into groups of how many you want to execute simultaneously, then process each group using `curl_multi_exec`.

```
$all_urls = ['http://www.google.com',
'http://www.yahoo.com',
'http://www.bing.com',
'http://www.twitter.com',
'http://www.wikipedia.org',
'http://www.stackoverflow.com'];

$chunked_urls = array_chunk($all_urls,3); //chunk into groups of 3

foreach($chunked_urls as $i => $urls) {

    $handles = [];    
    $mh = curl_multi_init();  
    
    foreach($urls as $url) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
        $handles[] = $ch;
    }
    
    // execute all queries simultaneously, and continue when all are complete
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running);
    
    foreach($handles as $handle) {
        file_put_contents("/tmp/output",curl_multi_getcontent($handle),FILE_APPEND);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $handle);        
    }
    
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    
    print "Finished chunk $i\n";
}
```