# Saving data from a curl multi init

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I am trying to understand how curl multi channel works. Having looked through several locations, including stackoverflow, I now have the following piece of code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, MY_STREAM_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, "true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  MY_LOGIN.":".MY_PWD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'get_stream');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 2000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME , 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$running = null;

$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);

do {
  curl_multi_select($mh, 1);
  curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);

} while($running > 0);

curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
curl_multi_close($mh);

function get_stream($ch, $data) {
    $length = strlen($data);
    echo 'Received '.$length.'B on '.date('Y-M-d H:i:s T');
    return $length;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that while this works, I am not really sure how to make good us of it (and the curl PHP manual did not have the detail I'm looking for).

What I need to do is grab the data, and write it out to a file when the cumulative data reaches 1MB, then start again with a new file. I'm sure once I figure it out, I'm going to say "duh", but in the meanwhile, I'm a bit confused.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

## Here's what I implemented:

```
function get_stream($ch, $data) {
    global $cum_data_size;
    global $data_buffer;
    $length = strlen($data);
    echo 'Received '.$length.'B at '.date('Y-M-d H:i:s T');
    $cum_data_size = $cum_data_size + $length;
    $data_buffer .= $data;
    if ($cum_data_size >= 1000000) {
        write_out_data_file();
    }
    return $length;
}

function write_out_data_file ()
{
    global $cum_data_size;
    global $data_buffer;
    $handle = fopen(DATA_FLDR.time().'_.gzip', 'w+');
    fwrite($handle, $data_buffer);
    fclose($handle);
    $data_buffer = '';
    $cum_data_size = 0;    
}
```

Comment: curl's multi functions are useful when you're trying to download multiple resources at the same time (i.e. you should be calling `curl_multi_add_handle` more than once). I'm not clear what you're trying to do but maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/24354616/3574819

Comment: I've already looked at this. I am only using a single handle in the example I posted to show just one handle. Whether I have one or more handles, what I want to do is grab the data, and save it to a file and when the file reaches 1MB, I want to save it and start saving data to another file

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2033444/3574819

Comment: I've seen this, but it seems as if something cleaner can be implemented. See my edit for what I've implemented, which I still think may not be "really" clean, but someone else here with more experience may be able to suggest a better answer.