# Curl Multi API Request - PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have the API request as outlined below which works fine (given the correct replacement of "xxxyyy"!) however I want to perform this call simultaneously with up to 5-10 different remote URLs. In the example below I've shown just 1 remote URL however I have an array of 10,000 urls which I would like to query as quickly as possible, all of which return the same structure in JSON.

After researching the topic I believe this can be done in PHP using Curl Multi, does anyone know if this is true, if so how would I go about this so i can call say 10 at once rather than each one individually?

```
<?php
$username = "xxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyy";
$password = "xxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyy";
$remote_url_1 = 'https://xxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyyxxxyyy_1.json';

{
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password");
$headers[] =  "X-Page:" . $pages;
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
'header' => $headers
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file1 = file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context);
$data = json_decode($file1, true);
$data2 = (array_values($data));
    $orderline_id = $data2[0];
    $orderline_sale_number = $data2[1];
    $orderline_status = $data2[2];
    $orderline_notes = $data2[3];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354616/download-list-of-files-simultaneously-in-php/24354819#24354819

Comment: For me this is the best script about working with curl_multi in PHP I have seen http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/